# get buttons name or ID on Google sheets with AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google sheets application, after add a button and clicked on it to run a script, it is possible with a function, to return the ID or name of clicked button?

My goal is to use an unique function for some buttons and detect, which button is clicked. ( ID or name of clicked button ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass arguments with buttons. A workaround would be to create a different function for each button and then pass the button name to a main function.

```
function button1() {myFunction("Button1");}
function button2() {myFunction("Button2");}

function myFunction(args) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!